# Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-s3

I am following below link for "Use Amazon S3 to Store a Single Amazon Elasticsearch Service Index"
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/use-amazon-s3-to-store-a-single-amazon-elasticsearch-service-index/

When I am trying

```
curl -XPUT 'http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/snapshot-repository' -d'{
    "type": "s3",
    "settings": {
        "bucket": "es-s3-repository",
        "region": "us-west-2",
        "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/es-s3-repository"
    }
}'
```

with update bucket, region and role_arn, but I am getting below error

`{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: iam:PassRole on resource: arn:aws:iam...}`

[image]

To resolve this issue, I followed this link https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/anonymous-not-authorized-elasticsearch/ also. but still It is not working.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to sign your requests to AWS Elasticsearch. The blog post that you linked describes using a proxy server to create the signature, did you do that?

As an alternative to using such a proxy server with curl, you can make the requests from a program. In the [AWS Elasticsearch docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-snapshots.html#es-managedomains-snapshot-registerdirectory) give you an example in Python, with a link to a Java client.

Comment: this answer is marked as accepted, so I guess it solved the problem for the one who asked it.... my question: looks good, but if I use boto 3 (as they say in the docs), how can i create a snapshot in S3 (similar to call "/_snapshot/")?

Answer (score 2):

I used postman with [AWS signature](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/authorization/aws-signature/).